# CDN only works assigned domain

Tags: django, nginx, subdomain, cdn

For example:
About www.abc.com , and en.abc.com

I want to know how to configure the CDN or somethings, make the CDN only works in www.abc.com, 
for en.abc.com don't works.

I am using aliyun.com as my cdn provider.

How about the NGINX or Django or Domain or CDN settings?

Comment: You need to say which CDN you're trying to configure.

Comment: ,Actually,CDN is www.aliyun.com CDN, It's in China. I would rather try to find a better way to configure NGINX,or Django or DNS system. @Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

CDN systems always 'only' work on their configured hostnames. Basically, a CDN is a reverse proxy with a set of rules on it. For any request coming in, it has to know

- where to fetch the content from
- which additional logic to apply to the content when delivering it

If you want to use a different hostname on the CDN, you will have to make the CDN work, all other components in your web site delivery will not be reached if the CDN configuration doesn't proxy the request to your web server.
I am not familiar with aliyun.com specifically, but there might be a chance to have them set up a wildcard/regex hostname (like *.example.com). You will have to get suport from aliyun to understand if this is possible.